# Button under ScrollView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, button, swiftui, uiscrollview

I have a `ScrollView` on top of a `Button` because I want the contents of the `ScrollView` to move over the top of the button when they are scrolled. However, currently this means that the button does not work, I presume because the scrollview is taking the touch events. Is there any way to have the button working in SwiftUI?

```
struct Test: View {
    @State var pressed:Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.pressed = true
                }) {
                    Text("Button")
                        .padding(20)
                        .accentColor(pressed ? Color.green : Color.red)
                }
                
                Spacer()
            }
            
            ScrollView {
                Spacer()
                    .frame(height:60)
                
                Color.gray
                    .frame(height:200)
                    .padding(10)
                
                Color.gray
                    .frame(height:200)
                    .padding(10)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Button and 3 gray rectangles vertically laid out]

Comment: ok, i am sorry, but i do not understand why you want to scroll over a button...!? Do you have a screenshot that explains why this makes sense? and yes, the touches will of course be caught by the scrollview...I am just very curious.

Comment: @Chris I want to have a header with a button that the user can use when the scrollview is scrolled to the very top but is not important when the user is scrolling through the list, I have attached a screenshot of the example code.

Comment: @BenJacob Have you found a way to solve this? I have the same problem.

Comment: @SteV8 same, did you find a solution?

Comment: @aheze I had to switch to UIKit.

Comment: You can do that with 2 ways: 1- put the button and the List inside a VStack, and the VStack inside a ScrollView. all that items goes to the list.
2- Add a .offset(y: 50) to the scrollview in your solution.

Answer (score -2):

you have to put the button last so that is is "over" the scrollview like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var pressed:Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView {
                Spacer()
                    .frame(height:60)

                Color.gray
                    .frame(height:200)
                    .padding(10)

                Color.gray
                    .frame(height:200)
                    .padding(10)

                Color.gray
                    .frame(height:200)
                    .padding(10)

                Color.gray
                    .frame(height:200)
                    .padding(10)

                Color.gray
                    .frame(height:200)
                    .padding(10)

                Color.gray
                    .frame(height:200)
                    .padding(10)
            }

            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.pressed = true
                    print("tapped")
                }) {
                    Text("Button")
                        .padding(20)
                        .accentColor(pressed ? Color.green : Color.red)
                }

                Spacer()
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would mean that the button would always be on top of the scrollview right? I want it to be underneath

Comment: yes, your r right. But how should this be possible if the scrollview should be over the button AND the button should be tappable!? Then you would have to manipulate hitTesting - func...else i don't have an idea how you will get his,...

Comment: This is why I posted this question, to ask how this would be possible

Answer (score -2):

1. Make the Image under the scrollView to show.
2. Make an invisible button frame over the ScrollView to use it.

1:

```
VStack{
    //Image Logo Start
    Image("img_Logo")
    .resizable()
    .padding(.all, 10.0)
    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.4, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.2)
    //Image Logo Done
}
```

2:

```
Button(action: {

    }) {

}.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
```